# Git push on branch says its up-to-date but it isn't

Tags: windows, git

A colleague on computer A pushed a branch, I checked it out locally on computer B. We pushed and pulled happily for a week.

I then pulled the branch down as M403 onto computer C, using `git checkout -b M403 remotes/origin/M403-Some-Feature` so my understanding is that this local branch tracks the remote.

My colleague and I sat at this computer and did a merge, from branch to master and in reverse. I then needed to share the changes to M403 to the server so we can get at it back at our normal computers.

When I pushed, I noticed it said `[new branch]`. A `git branch --all` shows another branch on the remote with the shortened name M403.

I pushed again but this time specifying the full path to the remote branch from where it came, `remotes/origin/M403-Some-Feature` but again it said `[new branch]`

From computer B, when I pull changes, it says its all up-to-date but I don't see the changes.

From computer C, when I push to any M403 branch using short or long name or anything, it says its up-to-date.

I added a change just to see, but even though computer C pushes it, it has gone into a black hole and pulling from anywhere else doesn't see the changes.

What happened?

**UPDATE**

- I deleted the old repo folder, recloned.
- Checked out the remote branch using `git checkout -t remotes/origin/Lalalala`
- Merged master.
- Pushed `git push` which it knew how to handle due to the `-t` tracking.
- Pulled on computer B and all is fine.

Who knows what went wrong the first time.

Comment: IMHO it's impossible to diagnose this without some actual screenshots / log outputs.

Comment: Yeah, possibly so. I have `master` updated and good so I'll reclone and do it all again and see if its repeatable. Keep the command line log.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git checkout -t remotes/origin/branch_name`

I can't say for sure what went wrong, I've been able to share a branch using `git checkout -b local_name remotes/origin/branch_name` for months, but this time it went wrong.

Doing it again with `-b` also failed again, an even weirder problem where a pull says its up-to-date and a push says there's pending changes to be pulled.

Using `-t` worked. In both cases, the branch-tracking was apparently configured correctly, with the status showing the commit gap between local and server.

Odd.